# Jquery click function with same button display different text

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello eveyone I'm trying to using click function.When user clicks the button, second text will appear and the first one will be display none and then user click again the same button this time third text will appear and the second text will be display  and finally click the same button again fourth text will appear third one display none. Here is my function:

```
$("#slider1next").click(function () {
    $(".text").css('display', '');
    $("#first_one").css('display','none');                   
});
```

here is the HTML

```
  <button id="slider1next" >Clickme</button>
  <p class="text" id="first_one">This is the first text</p>
  <p class="text" id="second_one" style="display:none">This is the second text</p>
  <p class="text" id="third_one" style="display:none">This is the third text</p>
  <p class="text" id="fourth_one" style="display:none">This is the four text</p>​
```

Also you can see there http://jsfiddle.net/ganymedes/7kxAE/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$("#slider1next").click(function () {
    $(".text:visible").hide().next().show();
});
```

In other words, with every click, you [`hide`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) the [`:visible`](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) text, and [`show`](http://api.jquery.com/show/) the [`next`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) one.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/joaopsilva/gjGvn/)**.

If you want to cycle back to the first one when you reach the last `p`, use the following instead:

```
$("#slider1next").click(function () {
    var $next = $(".text:visible").hide().next();
    $next.length ? $next.show() : $(".text:first").show();
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/joaopsilva/gjGvn/3/)**.
​

Comment: it will have bug, because will not find any next element after last element.

Comment: @TolgaArican: OP did not specify that he wants that behaviour, but I've provided an example to do it with a small modification.

Answer (score 1):

In order to revert back to beginning you need to check if there is a `next` otherwise use the first. `toggle()` method will reverse display of an element

```
$("#slider1next").click(function() {
    var $curr= $('.text:visible');
    var $next= $curr.next().length ? $curr.next() : $('.text').first()
    $curr.add( $next).toggle();  
});
```

DEMO  http://jsfiddle.net/XQJFQ/

Answer (score 0):

You have to get somehow which one is selected. Now you are only showing all texts. Then hiding only first one.

First change first element of html. You don't need to define id's. text class is enough.

```
<p class="text active">This is the first text</p>
```

Then change your click function

```
$("#slider1next").click(function () {

    // get current
    var cur = $('.text.active').index('.text');

    // calculate next
    var next = cur+1 % $('.text').length();

    // hide all
    $(".text").hide();

    // show next
    $($('.text')[next]).show();

    // update active
    $('.text.active').removeClass('active');
    $($('.text')[next]).addClass('active');
});
```